# Передать в делегат конструктор класса?

Tags: c#

Возможно ли в делегат в качестве параметра передать пользовательский конструктор - что бы при вызове конструктора срабатывал делегат а вместе с ним и событие типа этого делегата?

Есть класс. У него есть конструктор - пользовательский. При создании єкземпляра класса - конструктор вызывается. Нет ли возможности "просигнализировать" об этом - создав делегат и передав экземпляру этого делегата конструктор в качестве параметра. Создать событие типа этого делегата и тогда при срабатывании конструктора что бы вызывалось событие.

Comment: Объявите в этом классе статическое событие и дергайте его из конструктора

Comment: @PashaPash: Почему не как ответ?

Comment: @VladD я не уверен что правильно понял вопрос )

Answer (score 2):

```
class AwesomeClass
{
    public static event Action Constructed;

    public AwesomeClass()
    {
        Constructed();
    }

    public AwesomeClass(object obj):this()
    {
        //Only for example :D
    }

}

class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        AwesomeClass.Constructed += () => { Console.WriteLine("Class was constructed."); };

        var awesomeClass=new AwesomeClass();
        var awesomeClass3=new AwesomeClass(null);
        var awesomeClass4=new AwesomeClass();


        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

> Class was constructed.
>   Class was constructed.
>   Class was constructed.

P.s. Но на самом деле я бы не рекомендовал такое делать вообще, если появилась необходимость такого, то скорее всего архитектура продумана не лучшим образом :D